# Determinar si un input se encuentra entre dos valores

Tags: python, python-3.x

Recientemente compre un curso maestro de Python 3 en udemy y estoy resolviendo uno de mis ejercicios, en el cual se me pide que cree un pequeño programa que haga ciertas operaciones aritméticas con un número que el usuario introduzca, para lo cual me pide que verifique que sea un número, cosa que ya hice. Pero también le pide al usuario que introduzca un número del 1 al 9 y no se como lograr esto.
No para de darme errores con el print y con la variable llamada numero_usuario, ¿alguna idea de como arreglar esto?

````
numero_magico = 12345679
numero_usuario = int (input("Introduce un número del 1 al 9: "))
if numero_usuario >= 10 or numero_usuario <= 0:
    print ("Error, no es un número del 1 al 9.")
else:
numero_usuario *= 9
numero_magico *= numero_usuario
print ("El número mágico es: ", numero_magico) ```
````

Answer (score 1, accepted):

En Python, el indentado es obligatorio. El código de tu `else` no está indentado, por lo que tienes que indentar el código que va en esa rama.

Te da error en `numero_usuario` porque es lo primero que hay sin indentar cuando debería haberlo.

Comment: No sé exactamente que es eso, ¿como lo hago?

Comment: Listo, lo conseguí, ¡muchísimas gracias!